# My nickname violate the Google+ Names Policy, how about my privacy?

Tags: united-kingdom, internet, privacy, terms-of-service

I would like to use my [nickname](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/86257/22759) instead of full name when commenting on random posts within Google network.

However when I wanted to enforce that (by changing my Full Name into nickname), I found out that:

> The nickname that you've chosen appears to violate the [Google+ Names Policy](https://support.google.com/plus/answer/1228271).

I believe they meant this [policy](http://www.google.com/intl/en/+/policy/content.html).

However I am worried about my privacy and this was applied quite recently.

By which law I am enforced to share my personal details (such as my full name) on forum publicly to on-line people which I even don't know (when commenting on random posts)?

In other words, based on what law Google tries to enforces its restrictive policy, if any?

Can I do anything in that situation (e.g. my privacy is protected by any law), so I can enforce on my privacy rights without removing my Google Plus account? I'm from UK if that's matter.

Comment: The caveat here is that use of Google's services is at-will, you aren't forced to use it. Since there is nothing illegal with their ToS, there is nothing you can do to compel them otherwise (nor should there be).

Comment: I'm a bit confused upon review - they explicitly link to their Names Policy; why do you think they mean a different one?

Comment: @jimsug They've linked to Q&A which has only tips, so it doesn't look like a proper Policy Names as stated in the link name.

Comment: @kenorb Okay, that's fair enough (although it may be a _de facto_ policy if they call it and enforce it as one) - what makes you think that you violate the Names Policy or Content Guidelines because you haven't used your full name, though? For instance, have you tried using another full name (John Smith)?

Comment: @jimsug The message appeared when I've tried to enforce my nickname in fields where is Full name (as I couldn't leave it blank), so I think the system detected that nickname was copied into Full Name.

Comment: @kenorb does your nickname include numbers or symbols?

Comment: @jimsug The same as here, 'kenorb'.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> By which law I am enforced to share my personal details (such as my full name) on forum publicly to on-line people which I even don't know (when commenting on random posts)?

Contract Law. Google have made it a term of the contract that you use your full name. You can:

1. contact Google and negotiate a change to that term,
2. accept that term,
3. choose not to enter the contract.

> so I can enforce on my privacy rights without removing my Google Plus account?

As a person subject to UK law, your privacy rights involve limiting who and in what circumstances Google can divulge personal private information to. Your name is **not** personal private information; things like your medical history and bank balance are.

Aside from that, you do not have a right to privacy. Anything you do or say that is visible or audible from a public place (like the internet) or a private place where the person in control of that place does not insist on your privacy (i.e. almost everywhere that you are not in control of) is **public**!

Comment: Do UK privacy laws necessarily apply to companies based and operated in other countries, though? Even if they do, it's likely that enforcement of such laws would be at least impractical.

Comment: @jimsug yes and yes, however, the data is probably held by a UK subsidiary in this particular case

Comment: @jimsug National laws apply to companies which choose to do business in that country, and especially so if the company has a sizable presence there. It can be hard for the UK to enforce privacy laws against, say, a US high school debate team's website. It is easy to enforce against Google, which has thousands of employees in the UK and clearly intentionally targets the market.

Comment: @cpast I don't know about the last part, an Australian tried to bring a case against Google Australia for defamation in its web search, and the court found that as Google AU was not involved in operating Web Search they had no effective control over it, and the case was decided in favour of Google AU. Google AU has employees and presence in Australia.

Comment: @DaleM You're probably guessing when you say "probably", right? Unless you have evidence to suggest that they store that data in the UK?

Comment: @jimsug But the EU has successfully brought cases against Google Inc. That seems like more of a "who to sue" question.

Comment: @cpast Possibly. And perhaps a choice of forum issue, too. All I meant to point out is that just because some part of a business operates in a country, doesn't mean that they can, or will, be held accountable for the rest of, or other parts of, the business.

Comment: Upon review - I can't find text in the Terms or Policy/ies that require the User to use their full name, just FYI. not sure whether this affects your answer or not, since obviously they can't be bound by a clause that doesn't exist.

Comment: @jimsug It's very easy for an English claimant to enforce an English judgment against Google. Once they obtain the order in England they go to a court in California and seek to have it enforced on the basis of the judicial comity between the UK and the US. Only if there is a specific bar to that enforcement (such as the US SPEECH Act) will the court decline to enforce the order.

Comment: @jimsug However in order to bring proceedings against a foreign-domiciled person in an English court, you do need to obtain the court's permission before serving the claim form out of the jurisdiction. Basically you need to show that England is a reasonably appropriate venue for the trial, instead of somewhere else such as where the foreign defendant is domiciled. Against Google many parties have had success in obtaining permission to do this. See for instance http://www.bailii.org/cgi-bin/markup.cgi?doc=/ew/cases/EWHC/QB/2014/2808.html

Answer (score 4):

Google doesn't need a law to justify its Names Policy, and you don't have to use your full name or personal details. **There's no requirement in either the Google+ Names Policy or the Content Policy that you use your real name.**

Provided that Google's Terms of Service don't otherwise violate the law, they're under no obligation to allow you to use a pseudonym.

If you don't want to share your full name, don't. It's as simple as that.

*On the other hand*, provided that you otherwise comply with their requirements, you might be able to use any other combination of words as your Google+ name. They probably can't tell that your name is/isn't what you say it is, though even if they can't *prove* it they may still be able to take action to make you change it.